# Help me to identify this crystal oscillator module

Tags: oscillator, crystal, module

Please help me to identify the manufacturer of this crystal oscillator module so that I can search for its datasheet.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taitien. Found by searching for *crystal oscillator manufacturers logos*

Comment: thanks a lot for you support.